# pyqt5でmatplotlibを使いたい

Tags: python, python3, pyqt5

python3.5を使っています。pyqt5でmatplotlibを使いたいです。しかし、コードを書いてみたところ、ボタンは表示されるのですが、グラフが表示されません。
（レイアウトでなくて座標で指示したところにグラフを置きたかったので表示個所は意図的にコメントアウ‌​トしています）

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random

class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("グラフ")
        self.setGeometry(300,300,500,500)

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.move(0,0)


        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.hide()

        # Just some button 
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot',self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        self.button1.move(0,400)

        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Zoom',self)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.zoom)
        self.button2.move(100,400)

        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pan',self)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.pan)
        self.button3.move(200,400)

        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Home',self)
        self.button4.clicked.connect(self.home)
        self.button4.move(300,400)

        """
        # set the layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        btnlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        btnlayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        btnlayout.addWidget(self.button2)
        btnlayout.addWidget(self.button3)
        btnlayout.addWidget(self.button4)
        qw = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        qw.setLayout(btnlayout)
        layout.addWidget(qw)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        """

    def home(self):
        self.toolbar.home()
    def zoom(self):
        self.toolbar.zoom()
    def pan(self):
        self.toolbar.pan()

    def plot(self):
        ''' plot some random stuff '''
        data = [random.random() for i in range(25)]
        self.axes.plot(data, '*-')
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.setWindowTitle('Simple QTpy and MatplotLib example with Zoom/Pan')
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: もう少し行いたい事を説明し、質問のタイトルもそれに合わせていただくと回答が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: 分かりやすい質問編集ありがとうございます！参考にします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)` の下に `self.canvas.setParent(self)` と `self.canvas.move(100,20)` を加えることで無事動きました。

**修正後のプログラム:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random

class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("グラフ")
        self.setGeometry(300,300,500,500)

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.setParent(self)

        self.canvas.move(100,20)


        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.hide()

        # Just some button 
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot',self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        self.button1.move(0,400)

    def plot(self):
        ''' plot some random stuff '''
        data = [random.random() for i in range(25)]
        self.axes.plot(data, '*-')
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.setWindowTitle('Simple QTpy and MatplotLib example with Zoom/Pan')
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```